# What is the solution to find the IDs of the "max" n rows in a subset of a group?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have the table T with the following data and structure

```
__________________________
ID  |  Grp   |     Dt     |
____|________|____________|
1   |   A    |  2007-11-22|  
2   |   A    |  2008-01-03|  
3   |   A    |  2008-01-03|  
4   |   A    |  2011-04-13|  
5   |   B    |  2007-11-22|  
6   |   B    |  2010-04-28|  
7   |   B    |  2009-03-19|  
8   |   B    |  2007-11-22|  
9   |   C    |  2010-04-28|  
10  |   C    |  2009-03-19|  
11  |   C    |  2011-04-13|  
12  |   C    |  2012-02-22|  
13  |   D    |  2007-11-22|  
14  |   D    |  2010-04-28|  
15  |   D    |  2009-03-19|  
16  |   E    |  2007-11-22|  
17  |   E    |  2010-04-28|  
18  |   E    |  2011-04-13|  
19  |   F    |  2007-11-22|  
20  |   G    |  2007-11-22|  
21  |   H    |  2007-11-22|  
22  |   H    |  2010-04-28|  
23  |   H    |  2009-03-19|  
24  |   H    |  2008-03-15|
____|________|____________|
```

Given `@date_from = '2007-01-01'` and `@date_to = '2008-06-01'`
write a query that returns the max records of the filtered subset of @date_from to @date_to.

The result should be as follows:

```
__________________________
ID  |  Grp   |     Dt     |
____|________|____________|
2   |   A    |  2008-01-03|  
3   |   A    |  2008-01-03|  
5   |   B    |  2007-11-22|  
8   |   B    |  2007-11-22|  
13  |   D    |  2007-11-22|  
16  |   E    |  2007-11-22|  
19  |   F    |  2007-11-22|  
20  |   G    |  2007-11-22|  
21  |   H    |  2008-03-05|  
____|________|____________|
```

One possible solution is:

```
DECLARE @date_from AS DATE = '2007-01-01'
DECLARE @date_to   AS DATE = '2008-06-01'

WITH TFltr AS ( SELECT ID, Grp, Dt FROM T WHERE @date_from <= Dt AND Dt <= @date_to )
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Grp, t1.Dt 
FROM TFltr t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TFltr t2 ON t1.Grp = t2.Grp AND t1.Dt < t2.Dt
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

So do you know of a better/faster aproach to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the RANK analytic function:

```
DECLARE @date_from AS DATE = '2007-01-01'
DECLARE @date_to   AS DATE = '2008-06-01'

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, Grp, Dt,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY Dt DESC) AS DateRank
  FROM T
  WHERE Dt BETWEEN  @date_from AND @date_to) InnerT
WHERE DateRank = 1
```

The inner query ranks the dates high-to-low within each `Grp`. The highest date(s) get a `DateRank` of 1. The outer query then includes only those rows where `DateRank = 1`. I tried this query on the data in your post and got the results you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
select T1.*
from T T1
inner join
(
select max(dt) as max_dt, Grp
from T
where @date_from <= dt and dt <= @date_to
group by Grp
) X
on T1.Grp = X.Grp and T1.dt = X.max_dt
```

Comment: This one will work with a couple fixes: (1) swap the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` in the inner query and (2) end the join condition with `... and T1.dt = X.max_dt` (you have `t1.max_dt = X.dt`, which causes an "Invalid column" error).

Comment: Thanks graceemile.  Edits have been applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, Grp, Dt
from TFltr
where dt between @date_from  and @date_to
group by ID, Grp, Dt
having dt=max(dt)
```

I changed the query above to:

select ID as dt, Grp, Dt
from T
where dt between @date_from  and @date_to
group by ID, Grp, Dt
having dt=max(dt) and ID=max(ID)

I am getting "better" results, but it is not yet correct.

Comment: Because this groups by `ID` in addition to `Grp` and `Dt`, it will return all the rows between `@date_from` and `@date_to`. The results from this will include both `Grp=H` rows within the date range (`2007-11-22` and `2008-03-15`) rather than just the highest (`2008-03-15`).

Comment: I believe you mean from T not from TFltr

Comment: My bad! I especially like the solution using the RANK function below.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/008f4/12)**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TFltr t
WHERE t.Dt >='2007-01-01'
AND t.Dt <= '2008-06-01'
AND t.Dt = (SELECT MAX(h.Dt)
            FROM TFltr h
            WHERE h.Dt >='2007-01-01'
            AND h.Dt <= '2008-06-01' 
            AND h.Grp = t.Grp)
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Result:

```
| ID | GRP |                              DT |
----------------------------------------------
|  2 |   A |  January, 03 2008 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 |   A |  January, 03 2008 00:00:00+0000 |
|  5 |   B | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
|  8 |   B | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
| 13 |   D | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
| 16 |   E | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
| 19 |   F | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
| 20 |   G | November, 22 2007 00:00:00+0000 |
| 24 |   H |    March, 15 2008 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Your Query:

```
DECLARE @date_from AS DATE = '2007-01-01'
DECLARE @date_to   AS DATE = '2008-06-01'

SELECT t.*
FROM TFltr t
WHERE t.Dt >=@date_from
AND t.Dt <= @date_to
AND t.Dt = (SELECT MAX(h.Dt)
            FROM TFltr h
            WHERE h.Dt >=@date_from
            AND h.Dt <= @date_to 
            AND h.Grp = t.Grp)
ORDER BY t.ID
```